# A question on the application of Ito's lemma

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-differential-equations, change-of-variable

I am reading a paper in which the author applies Ito's lemma to show that a particular process is a local martingale.

Given an SDE $dZ(t)=\frac{a_i^+(Z(t))}{Z(t)}dt+\sqrt{a_i^+(Z(t))}dW(t)$, the author computes the Stochastic differential of $M(t):=\log Z(t)$ using Ito's lemma.
and claims that the stochastic differential of $M(t)$ is given by

$dM(t)=\frac{\sqrt{a_i^+(Z(t))}}{Z(t)}dW(t)$
He then goes ahead and uses a theorem on Local martingales to make conclusions on the process $M(t)$ which is crucial in the proof.

Shouldn't the stochastic differential be
$dM(t)=\frac{\sqrt{a_i^+(Z(t))}}{Z(t)}dW(t)+\frac{1}{2} \frac{a_i^+(Z(t))}{Z(t)}{Z(t)^2}dt$ instead? I am also attaching the screenshot of the paper

You can find the paper here https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s12044-013-0141-8( the text just under equation (3.5) ) . 
**(Note that there is $a$ instead of $a_i$ which is a typo among the many typos and mistakes in the paper.)**
[image: A q]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, the trend term only gets reduced by half. Reversing the calculation, starting with $Z=\exp(M)$, gives in the Ito formula
$$
dZ=Z(dM+\frac12d\langle M\rangle )
$$
where the quadratic variation is $d⟨M⟩=\frac{a^+(Z)}{Z^2}dt$, so that the original equation should have been
$$
dZ=\sqrt{a^+(Z)}dW + \frac12\frac{a^+(Z)}{Z}dt.
$$
The question now is, is this a genuine error or was the factor 2 in the denominator lost in print?

Comment: If it was an error in print why would the author say it’s local martingale ? He goes ahead in the paper saying that it’s a local martingale and using a theorem ( which assumes that it’s a local martingale to prove the theorem in question . ) what’s strange is that it’s a springer journal and this is in my opinion a blatant error since it breaks down the proof completely

Comment: I do not have access to the article, so I can not check print-error vs. mathematical error.

Comment: Can’t you access the link to the paper I posted above ?

Comment: I'd have to figure out how to pay Springer the $42 demanded for this one article, and if I want that.

Comment: Oh I am sorry . I had direct access since I was accessing it from the university , so I thought perhaps it was free

Comment: Here is a free link , just in case you might want to have  a look. Thank you very much for all your help. https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=2ahUKEwiN8_LNzdTiAhWC-6QKHc6kCFkQFjACegQIBRAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ias.ac.in%2Farticle%2Ffulltext%2Fpmsc%2F123%2F03%2F0443-0454&usg=AOvVaw0BvXNHK83zd6R2WojMz4RT

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/0904.2629 could be the earliest version, I also found your link. It does not look like an accident. Now if you could produce a short counter-example, it would have chances to get published there.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking out the time to look at this paper .  I am going to try to think of one .